# ASCII code of non UTF-8 character in C

Tags: c, encoding, utf-8, utf-16

I want to make a spell corrector in C. As such, reading accented words is necessary. But when I try to print out the ASCII code of, ie `à` for instance:

```
printf("%d",'à');
```

It prints out garbage. So, is this even possible?

Comment: Posting the output is more informative that describing the output with "prints out garbage. "  What was the output?

Comment: `'à'` is not   [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) .

Comment: That character is not ascii encoded, so there is no ascii code to print out.

Comment: I think you need wide character https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/wchar.h

Comment: Something which looks like `à` on your terminal might look very different on some other terminal. Do not use the "extended" ASCII. Moreover, if it looks like `à` in your editor, it doesn't mean it will look the same in your terminal.

Comment: If your source file is utf-8, this should raise a compile time warning at the least, since `'à'` is actually the two bytes `0xc3` and `0xa0` in utf-8. And those don't fit into a `char`.

Comment: @dhke In C, `'à'` is not a `char`, it is an `int`.  `'\xc3\xa0'` is a legitimate character constant that hopefully should cause a _multi-character character constant_ warning.

Comment: @chux It *may* be an `int` since treatment of multibyte character literals is implementation dependent. And yes, gcc makes it an `int`, so the output is probably `50080` (i.e. `0xc3a0`). Clang simply croaks out with "character too large for enclosing character literal type"

Comment: @dhke, `'\xc3\xa0'` is a wholly standard conforming [integer character constant](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4).  The standard specifies that it's type is `int` (as is the type of `'A'`).  The standard leaves the *value* of that constant to the implementation, but not its type.

Comment: Though the character 'à' is not encoded by ASCII, it *does* have a (multibyte) representation in UTF-8-encoded Unicode.  I'm not sure, then what the title is trying to convey by describing it as a "non UTF-8 character".

Comment: I bet he means ascii > 127

Comment: What "garbage" is it printing out? What value were you expecting? Do you have a reference for the character set that you're consulting to assist us in understanding which character set you're working with? ASCII is a 7-bit encoding, so anything beyond 0x7F (127) is an 8-bit char (not ASCII). [There are several possible encodings for that character.](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00E0/charset_support.htm) For example, ISO-8859-1 and Windows-1252 use 0xE0 (224) like Unicode while IBM code pages 437 and 850 use 0x85 (133). UTF-8 encodes it as 0xC3A0 (50080). See my link for more.

Comment: If the source file is saved in a Latin-based encoding, `à` could be encoded as a single byte like `\xe0` instead of a multi-byte UTF encoding like `\xc3\xa0`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Actually [here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4p10), but thanks. I need to read up on current C, then :)

Comment: It doesn't really matter what the source file character encoding is _as long as the compiler is accurately told which it is_ (which could be what @RemyLebeau is getting at). What matters for string and char literals is the execution character encoding.